# Editar una Imagen JPG con BufferedImage en Java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando cargar una Imagen de un mapa cualquiera en un JLabel y al hacer click sobre este mapa se dibuje un "puntero" exactamente donde hice click y esta imagen quede editada con el nuevo puntero, para ello estoy usando un MouseListener , pero mi programa no dibuja nada al hacer click.

```
package mapa;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Signal {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Signal window = new Signal();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public Signal() throws IOException {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void initialize() throws IOException {

    BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\BryanPC\\Desktop\\SanFierro.jpg"));
    Graphics2D map = image1.createGraphics();

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 477, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 461, 400);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel containerImg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image1));
    containerImg.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            BufferedImage pointer = null;

            try {

                pointer = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\BryanPC\\Desktop\\smallPointer.png"));

                map.drawImage(pointer, e.getX(), e.getY(), null);

                map.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 50);

            } catch (IOException e1) {

                System.out.println("The url is invalid");

            }

        }
    });
    panel.add(containerImg);
    containerImg.setBounds(10, 11, 441, 318);
    ;
}
```

}

Comment: No he trabajado hace tiempo con esto, pero según veo, estás mostrando tu imagen una sola vez (al cargar tu método), y no cada vez que se hace click, por que tu evento, al ser asíncrono, ocurre posteriormente a cuando se mostró la imagen por primera vez. Te recomiendo volver a pintar la imagen cad vez que se haga click

Comment: Y como se podría volver a pintarla después de cada click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia la linea donde dibujas el ovalo el la lineas de código:

```
map.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 50);
```

Por:

```
frame.getGraphics().drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 50);
```

Así dibujas encima de la ventana que tiene la imagen. O la otra opción es primero dibujar el ovalo en la imagen y luego pintar la imagen, tendrías que cambiar el orden de las lineas en el evento del mouse.